# How to share my saved video through whatsapp in windows Phone 8.1

Tags: whatsapp, video, lumia

Please help me out here, I have saved a video from net in my windows mobile but when i wanted to share it via whatsapp, i am not able to see this video anywhere- Albums/Document. 
There is no specific "video" option available in whatsapp and in whatsapp->albums also i can see only those videos which are captured by my camera or have downloaded from whatsapp.

Answer (score 4):

Update : The second method was found helpful by the author, so try it first.

You can share your video using the following steps

**Method 1 : From inside whatsapp**

1. Open whatsapp
2. Click on the attach icon.
3. Select documents in the list.
4. Now the "Choose an app screen will appear".
5. Choose Files app.
6. Browse to the folder and select the video file.

**Method 2 : From Files app**

1. Open Files app.
2. Navigate to the folder where the video is, usually *downloads*.
3. Click on share button.
4. Select Whatsapp.

Comment: Okay, Second Method helped actually. Thank you so much :-)

Comment: You are welcome.